# An issue in constructing the real numbers using Cauchy sequences in the rationals.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I'm having trouble justifying why we can discuss Cauchy sequences before the real numbers are constructed. As we know, the definition of a Cauchy sequence (in the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$) starts with "For every $\epsilon > 0 \dots$," which is where my issue lies. Suppose we use an irrational $\epsilon > 0$ that hasn't been constructed yet. How do we know that the equivalence class of Cauchy sequences representing $\epsilon$ satisfies the criterion for being Cauchy with this value of $\epsilon$ if it hasn't been defined yet?

Answer (score 1):

You define a Cauchy series of rationals only for rational $\epsilon$. It doesn't change the definition. You could define Cauchy sequence by restricting $\epsilon$ to be of th form $1/n$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For the definition of convergence, and of Cauchy sequences, it suffices to only consider rational $\epsilon$, or even only $\epsilon$'s of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, $n\in \mathbb N$. So you don't need to already have the reals constructed just to define limits/Cauchy sequences.